# Clouformation assumable role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a role, let's call it RoleA. RoleA is an already existing role in my AWS account and cannot easily be altered.

I have a CloudFormation script that deploys a new Role, call it RoleB.

Is it possible to allow RoleA to assume RoleB by editing the cloud formation script that deploys RoleB and making no alterations to RoleA?

Comment: Read about Trust Policy at [IAM Terms and Concepts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Because allowing `IAM Role` to assume you need to have make sure the source role can assume the destination and destination role allowing the source role in `trust policy`

[IAM Tutorial: Delegate access across AWS accounts using IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html)

[Roles terms and concepts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html)

> To delegate permission to access a resource, you create an IAM role in the trusting account that has two policies attached. The permissions policy grants the user of the role the needed permissions to carry out the intended tasks on the resource. The trust policy specifies which trusted account members are allowed to assume the role